# How to declare a generic structure that accepts any function?

Tags: rust

I need to implement a simple FSM with memory:

```
pub struct Fsm<TFunc> {
    memory: Vec<TFunc>
}
```

However in my sample the `TFunc` is any type, how to bound it to `callable` or `function`? In short, to I could use only functions as a type.

Is it possible in **rust**?

**ADDED**
To be clear I need the next behaviour:

```
fsm1 = Fsm::<Fn(usize)->usize>::new(); // Ok
fsm2 = Fsm::<Fn(usize, String)>::new(); // Ok
fsm3 = Fsm::<String>::new(); // Failed! It's not a function
```

Comment: @kmdreko, unfortunately, yap, functions can have any signature. Of course, it is the best variant to specify a signature as generic types but I think it's impossible. At least, to guarantee `TFunc` is a callable type.

Comment: @kmdreko, functions can have different signatures in different instances of `Fsm`, there is a single signature per same instance of `Fsm`.

Comment: @kmdreko, yeah, that's right! And to, for example, `Fsm<Fn(usize, String) -> usize>` was valid too... Any function but all functions in `Fsm` instance will have same signature.

Comment: @kmdreko, I've updated my question to show valid and invalid samples.

Comment: This may be an X/Y problem. In general, it's better _not_ to constrain type arguments on a struct. Instead accept any argument but constrain the `impl`s or methods. You can't call a function with an unknown number of arguments or arguments of unknown types, so these concrete types will need to be known somewhere, and it would be useful to see where you need to draw that line in your abstraction.

Comment: @PeterHall, I see, thank you for advice! I won't constraint it... but just for better understanding of **rust** generics, is it possible or not?

Comment: Abstracting over _all_ functions is a bit meaningless because you can't call a function without knowing its signature. I suspect that there is some extra information needed into order to understand your real problem.